# The for loop is working but without any good

Tags: r

I am using R to do a ML project, I have prepared the dataset and split the data into 10 equal splits but the problem is I need to fit the model 10 times manually (10-fold CV). I have tried to create train and test data using a for loop but each time it runs, train is the whole dataset and test is null. Can someone help me, please?

```
# Preparing the data

data <- read.csv("./project.csv")

id <- seq(1:103342)

data[, 'id'] <- id

for (i in 3:8) {
  data[,i] <- as.factor(data[,i])
}



# splitting the data into 10 equal data frames

f <- rep(seq(1, 10), each=round(103342/10), length.out=103342)

df <- split(data, f)

lapply(df, dim)


# running 10-fold cross-validation and computing error rate and AUC for each run.

results <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol=2, dimnames= list(c(), c('error_rate', 'auc')))

for (i in 1:10) {
  train <- data[!(data$id %in% df$`i`$id),]
  test <- df$`i`
  print(dim(test)) # Here is my problem the print statement will print null 10 times
  glm.fit <- glm(canceled ~ ., data=train, family=binomial)
  glm.prob <- predict(glm.fit, newdata=test, type="response")
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the `test <- df$\`i\`` syntax from but that's not how R does things. I think you instead want `test <- df[[i]]]`

Comment: This syntax is generated by the split function in R, if you split a data frame for example into 3 splits then you type ``df$`1` `` it will retrieve the first split.

Comment: But you can't use `$` with variables such as `i`. The dollar sign is just a short cut for literal values only. You need to use the double brackets `[[ ]]` when working with variables. And it's far more common in R code to see `df[[1]]` rather than `df$\`1\``

Comment: Many thanks, I will try the double brackets

Comment: That error message makes it sound like you are still using the dollar sign in addition to the brackets. You use one or the other. It should just be `test <- df[[i]]]` as I wrote in the first comment and then `data$id %in% df[[i]]$id` for the other

Comment: yep, I have just notice that I haven't remove it